# What is the most efficient way to write one item to a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, file, synchronization

I'm writing a script that is supposed to check two directories, one source, and one destination, then automatically copy all the new folders from the source directory into the destination directory, then copy down the name of the folder that was copied into a text file or .csv file which will be checked in the future to avoid duplicates, because the folders in the destination directory are going to be renamed.

I'm assuming .csv files are superior to text files for storing large amounts of separate small strings, but in the csv module for python there only appears to be a way to write the iterables into the file. I'm only going to be writing in one string per row at a time. Does it make more sense to store this one string in a list than use csv.writerow, or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You should try pandas for this. You want to store the names of the folder from which the files were copied right?

Comment: 1. CSV files *are* text files. 2. Performance difference between implementations is going to be insignificant for only one entry. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In python, the CSV writer will write every value in a single list as a single row. The best way to do this is by storing all of the items in a list of lists. for example

```
rows = [ ['Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0'],
         ['Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1'],
         ['Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3'],
         ['Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5'],
         ['Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8'],
         ['Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1']]
```

Each list here will be a separate line in a csv.

Another way of doing this, if you are going the route of making everything a single string, is to use newlines to seperate each row.

EG:

```
rows = "value1,value2,value3\n newRow1,newRow2,newRow3"
```

Either way will work.

I referred to this page for the example:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/

Comment: I'm trying to write one piece of data at a time. I'm looping through a list of folders one at a time, so I will have only one string at a time handy, a string with the name of the folder, and I want to add this to a text document or .csv, which ever is easier to work with. There is no row of values or list of values at any point.

Comment: you could loop through all of your folders and construct one large string before inserting it all at once to the CSV. If you seperate each element with a newline '\n' you should be able to seperate each element into a different row. Theres no need to access the csv as many times as you have rows.

Comment: I would only be accessing the .csv once at the beginning of the file, where I load everything from the .csv into a set, the later when I'm looping through folders, if I find a folder that needs to be copied, I add the name of the folder to the set, then write it to the .csv, then copy it. I suppose it might just be easier using a plain text file for that?

Comment: @GeneralTully i think it might be easier if you give code, im not exactly sure what you need.

Comment: `for item in srcDir:
    srcPath = os.path.join(src, item) #these are the full paths to each specific file
    dstPath = os.path.join(dst, item) '
    
    if item not in record and os.path.isdir(srcPath):
        record.add(item)
        #right here is where I want to write the folder name to the .csv
        
        #shutil.copytree(srcPath, dstPath)                                                                                   ` that is the main loop, all it is doing is looping through a folder looking for new files, writing the names down and copying if new. trouble formatting

Answer (score 0):

There are different programming languages, such as Python, Java, and C# for processing large files for geospatial data.
but the best way to write CSV files in Python is because you can easily extract **millions of rows within a second or minute** and You can read, write or You can perform many operations through Python programming.

But IF you are not a **programmer** then you can take the help of any application software such as **EmEditor** or any.

<---How to Write on application software--->
CSV Editor

Open the CSV Editor. Open the editor from the Query Tools menu.

Filter & Sort the Data. From the column pop-up menu, you can set filters or sort the data.

Edit the Data. Double-click any cell to edit its content.

Save Format. Use 'File / Save As' to save the edited CSV under a given file and format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil

base_path = "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/"
from_folders = ["New folder (2)/", "New folder/"]
to_folder = "Target/"

from_paths = list(map(lambda folder_name:base_path + folder_name, from_folders))
files_list = list(map(lambda path:[path + p for p in os.listdir(path)], from_paths))
target_path = base_path + to_folder

[list(map(lambda path:shutil.copy(path, target_path), paths)) for paths in files_list]

pd.DataFrame(from_paths, columns = ["From Paths"]).to_csv(f"{base_path}From Paths.csv")
```

I think the code would work fine if you just change `base_path`, `from_folders`, and `to_folder` according to your needs.